# I am getting null value when i am try to upload Image using retrofit

Tags: java, android

I am getting null value when I am try to upload image using Retrofit. This is actually happen only Xioami A2 Lite. I don't understand what is the issue here.

Here is my code

```
public void setFinalResponseMutableLiveData(final Context context, Uri fileuri, final PhotoView photoView, final String title) {
    photoView.onPhotoLoading();
    if (NetworkHelper.hasNetworAccess(context)){
        // create upload service client
        File file=new File(FileUtils.getPath(context,fileuri));
        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse(context.getContentResolver().getType(fileuri)),
                        file
                );

        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
        MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);

        // add another part within the multipart request
        String descriptionString = title;
        RequestBody description =
                RequestBody.create(
                        okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);

        RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getImageResponse(description,body).enqueue(new Callback<PhotoUploadResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<PhotoUploadResponse> call, Response<PhotoUploadResponse> response) {
                        photoView.onPhotoLoaded();
                        if (response.isSuccessful()){
                            finalResponseMutableLiveData.setValue(response.body());
                        }
                        else {
                            new CustomMessage((Activity)context,response.message());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<PhotoUploadResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        photoView.onPhotoLoaded();
                        new CustomMessage((Activity)context,t.getMessage());
                        Log.d("CURRENT", "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
                    }
                });

    }
    else {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                photoView.onPhotoLoaded();
                photoView.onInternetError();
            }
        },100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details, like a number of line, or point at the variable name with null value or other problem

Comment: getting null here 
MediaType.parse(context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().getType(fileuri)),
                            file

Comment: What is the value of 'fileuri'?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply to where the null value error is coming from, check where:

```
setFinalResponseMutableLiveData(final Context context, Uri fileuri, final PhotoView photoView, final String title)
```

is getting called at. At its calling point, make sure your fileuri is not null by setting a breakpoint and watching the values unfold in the debugger. As you have defined fileuri as a Non-nullable field, passing it a null value will crash the application.